# UITableView editing not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a button (a UINavigationBarItem) used for editing my UITableView, which only allows deletions. So when I press delete, the little red line comes up next to each cell, and I can delete each row.

When the button is pressed, the following function is called:

```
-(void)editButtonSelected:(id)sender {

    if(self.editing)
        NSLog(@"self.editing = true");
    else
        NSLog(@"self.editing = false");

    if(self.editing) {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [tableView reloadData];
        [leftButton setTitle:@"Delete"];
        [leftButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
        self.editing = false;
    }
    else {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [tableView reloadData];
        [leftButton setTitle:@"Done"];
        [leftButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
        self.editing = true;
    }
}
```

And it works fine. But only for a while. As soon as I introduce a new UIViewController, and then dismiss that controller, this delete function doesn't work on this main screen I have. It works fine until a new UIViewController is put on top. The button itself works fine, and the value of self.editing does get toggled between true and false correctly, but the little red lines do not show up. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Why are you calling `[super setEditing:animated:]` and then `self.editing = /* ... */;`. Self's implementation should call super's automatically. This probably isn't the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the target on your UINavigationBarItem is still set to the first view controller, not the subsequent view controllers that get pushed on the stack.

Comment: can you explain a little more detail? how would I fix this?

Comment: When you're creating your UINavigationBarItem (either programmatically or in IB) you're setting a target (your first view controller) and a selector (editButtonSelected: in this case).  Without changing that target to any new view controller's being pushed on the navigation stack, it will still call the editButtonSelected: method on the main view controller.

Comment: but that's what I want it to do. I want the main view controller (which has the UITableView) to show the little red lines.

Comment: I think I understand better now.  After pushing a new view controller, then popping that view controller, the editing logic no longer works.  Before I could try to answer again, I would need to see more code, specifically how you're creating the UINavigationBarItem and how you're pushing and popping the secondary UIViewControllers.

Comment: turns out the [tableView reloadData] call isn't working. all the tableview methods aren't being called. wonder why?